# Adding swift file into Objective-c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to add .swift file into existing Objective-c project and make access to objective-c file

Answer (score -1):

1. Create `.swift` file suppose `newSwiftController.swift`
2. automatically bridging file get appeared allow it to be created.
3. add `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` into implementation .m file 
   where you want to access your newly created `.swift` file.
4. go to project target - Build Setting -> search for *Defines module* and set it to *YES*